# Assign result of Java lambda to field

Tags: java, lambda

I want to use a lambda in Java to configure a field on an object at creation time. This means that I have to invoke the lambda inline, but I have seen no examples that run a lambda before first assigning it to something. Specifically I want to do something like this:

```
private JTextField tfInput = () -> { JTextField tf = JTextField(""); tf.setEditable(false); return tf; }();
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: What's the point? Why not run the statements directly?

Comment: Because doing it inline makes it so at no point in other functions will tf.getEditable() be false (by default at least). Anyway, I can decide later if this coding style is good. I just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: I think you could put `tfInput = new JTextField(""); tfInput.setEditable(false);` in the constructor.  I don't see what the lambda would be for.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to cast the lambda to a functional interface first:

```
private JTextField tfInput = (Supplier<JTextField>)(() -> {
    JTextField tf = new JTextField("");
    tf.setEditable(false);
    return tf;
}).get();
```

But I'm not sure why you'd opt for this instead of declaring a simple method, or initializing from the constructor or an initializer block. Also, note that if you're trying to make sure the field is only visible after it's initialized, you may need to make it `final` or `volatile`.

Comment: It may even be more efficient to create a method that does this.

Comment: @Killjoy1221: …or let the constructor do this, which is even simpler: `private JTextField tfInput; { tfInput = new JTextField(""); tfInput.setEditable(false); }`. The OP’s goal of having no possibility to see an editable text field is achieved with the same restrictions as with the lambda variant.